# Estimating Parameters of Optimal Posting Strategy from "Enhancing Trading Strategies with Order Book Signals"

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency

I'm reading the paper “[Enhancing Trading Strategies with Order Book Signals](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2668277)” by Cartea et al (2015). And I have the following questions:

1. Assume that I empirically estimated $\lambda^{l}, \lambda^{\pm}, \epsilon^l, \epsilon^{\pm}, T_{JK}^l, T_{JK}^{\pm}$ in way proposed in paragraph 4.1. Estimating Model Parameters on page 21. How can I build posting areas like the ones given on Figure 6 using this values? How to calculate $\Sigma_{\gamma}^{\pm}(t, q, J)$?
2. According to this optimal posting strategy should I always post my limit orders on best bid/ask or it could be posted deeper in the LOB? How to combine it with some inventory-based strategy like Avellaneda-Stoikov Market Maker strategy that recalculates bid and ask quotes using current inventory and mid-price.

Comment: Seems that the correct link to the abovementioned paper should be [this](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2668277).

Comment: Pls consider adding details to your question so that it can still be understood even if the link is broken or changed.